# I thought I did or I thought I had done

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

You get into your car and then you are trying to start the car but it's not working then you realize that the car doesn't have any fuel .What would you say? 
I think the second one should be the answer but I am not sure.

1-***I thought I filled up the car .***

2-***I thought I had filled up the car .***

Comment: There is no right answer. They are both grammatical.

Comment: Is there any difference in the meaning ? and what would native speakers say if they were in that situation

Comment: @TalhaÖzden They would probably say: **I thought I'd filled up the car.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing to choose between them. The narrative is already fixed at a point (in the past) later than the not-filling, so the past perfect ("had filled") is possible. But there is no other meaning that the simple past ("filled") could plausibly have here, so it is not necessary to use the past perfect for clarity, and many people would use the simple past.